# Get physical location of text in UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uilabel

I know how to find the size of the text by using `sizeWithFont` but what I really want to do is find the actual highest point and lowest point of the text that has been drawn in a `UILabel`.

I need to add an artificial cursor to a view with a `UILabel` within it. The problem is that the text in a `UILabel` seems to change its top and bottom margins arbitrarily. I can't work out how the OS works out where to position the text in the `UILabel`.

So what would be great is to be able to create a category or method which works out the Y axis pixel origin of the actual text drawn onto the view.

Is this possible at all? How does UITextField position text and the cursor perfectly?

**UPDATE**

I was thinking this might be possible by getting the UILabel context and finds the whitespace at the top, which should give me the Y pixel origin of the actual text right? I have no idea where to even start with this though, or make it efficient enough to not inhibit frequent changes to the UILabel.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does `[UITextField textRectForBounds:]` not give you what you want?

Comment: It doesn't seem to change height if the font size decreases (auto shrink UILabel)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a UILabel or could you use a disabled UITextView?

For a text view you could do something like

```
CGRect rect = [textView.layoutManager usedRectForTextContainer:textView.textContainer];
```

This should give you what you want. If memory serves the rect that it returns will be relative to the text view.

Hope this helps :)